# How to add SharePoint Document Library web part on a team site page?

Tags: document-library, publishing-page, term-store, team-sites

I have created a Document Library in SharePoint and I want to post it on the team site, so instead of it being in site contents everybody can see it and interact with it on project portal. I was told I need to use Term Sets to do so.

How do I put a created library on the team site so that the folders are visible and interactable?

Comment: Edit the page where you want to have the document library and add it from "App Parts" (2013/16) or webparts (2010).  It will then be added to the page and you can use it directly from there. The library must exist in the same site where it were created.

Comment: hi, your question is unclear- do you need to use the document library on the same site, or a sub site of that site? Content Query web part might be also another way to do it. I am confused why you need Term Sets- I wonder the person who suggested that meant configuring search based on tags on that library ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your Head Question **How to put SharePoint Document Library on team site?** and what I understood you need to show Doc library at Team Site page not within Site Contents.

So the answer should be as the following :

- Edit your page at your Team Site.

[image]

- From the above Ribbon > Insert Tab > Add web part or App Part.
- From Apps Category > Select your Document Library Name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Untested.  Worked in 2010.

Go to the site that has the list view you want.  Add a content editor webpart with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div[allowExport="false"]').attr("allowExport","true");
});
</script>
```

Now you can export the webpart you want.

Next, open the .webpart file in notepad and look for

```
<property name="WebId" …>all_zeros_guid_here </property>
```

Replace the zeros with the GUID of the site the list is on.  You can get it by going to _layouts/sitemanager.aspx  When you hover over a site in the right side, the GUID is displayed at the bottom left of the window.  ScreenCapture it and type it in.

Save and upload webpart

Thanks to: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/03/sharepoint-one-library-multiple-sites.html

Gotchas apply and include:

Only within site collection; Not tested with all list/lib; Will error while you allow editing of content type on target list

---

Alternate methods to aquire site GUID, from Mike Smith's Tech Training Notes

1) Wiki home page: 
Works for SP 2010 only: Display a Team Site home page (a wiki home page, home.aspx) that has at least one list web part, view the source of the page (right-view source) and search for "RelatedWebId"  (you could temporarily add an Announcements or library web part to the page)
    WebPartWPQ2_RelatedWebId="{f70832a4-5d0d-4265-a344-ea10a0007160}"

2) Tree View: 
Works for both SP 2007 and SP 2010: Go to Site Actions, Site Settings, Tree View and enable Tree View. Then go to any page, view source and search for "ListNode:"
   spNavigateHierarchy(this,'','30:ListNode:f70832a4-5d0d-4265-a344-ea10a0007160:740...